# Going back multiple pages on Salesforce Mobile App

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a setup where I take the details from one VFP and then load them into another VFP after navigating to it. However there needs to be a way to return to the original page after either the second page is saved or cancelled. My solution (using window.history.go(-2)) works fine for desktop, however on android and iOS it just isn't running at all. Window.history.back works just fine, but it returns to the previous record page which I don't want it to do. If there's any recommendations for something that can replace the go function I'm all ears for it, or any other advice.

This is the return navigation code

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("CompFromVisit")[0].style.display == "none")
    window.history.go(-2);
```

Edit:
So I've figured out that it's not doing anything because for some reason the app doesn't handle history in the same way that the web version does. So when I call histroy.go(-2) it's looking at a history with only length 1, so it does nothing. So I guess, any alternatives to history.go?

Edit2:
Also, it appears to only happen on the iOS version of the Salesforce App, android version is working fine.

Comment: Seems some kind of wizard, have you thought about adding a link to previous screen on the destination page. Generally changing history is quite confusing for users and can cause bad behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "adding a link to previous screen on the destination page". This separate page is being generated from either a Contact or Account detail page so each URL is dynamic. The button to get to them unfortunately just link to a URL as well, so I can't store the return address in say the window session data.